# How to configure telerik's asp.net compnet on Somee.com webserver

Tags: asp.net, telerik

I am using a free account in [somee.com](http://somee.com). 

I have few queries related to this.

- How can I configure and view the style components of telerik on web.
- (if someone tried) Where can I find IIS settings in somee.com so If I want to modify anything there.
- If you guys have any information about **free asp.net hosting sites/server** so please share.I am a student and I want to try website which was build in asp.net

Comment: Doesn't look like you are really questioning about code here. Except the firs question which is in some way related to asp, the other two have nothing to do with SO. However, There is nothing special to configure to see the Telerik controls on an asp page and nothing to do on the IIS. Just drag the controls on the page and they will register in the web.config.
About some.com, you do not have access to the IIS, what do you won't to modify there?

Comment: Does somee support for full trust permission? I never try free hosting. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I configure and view the style components of telerik on web.

**Telerik [RadProgressArea](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/progressarea/examples/fileuploadintegration/defaultcs.aspx) requires Full Trust level.**

As long as you do not use RadProgressArea, it should be fine with most share hosting site.

*If you have questions regarding server, you can ask at [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/).*